# Razor Html.Editor set default value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have searched but no good solution for now.

I try using is like:

**@Html.Editor("userName", new { htmlAttributes = new { value = "ABC" } })**

Though, the value doesn't want to appear in renderred HTML. 
I need to use Editor element as well as this is kind of 'search' field.

Do you know how is it possible to pass value to Html.Editor?

Comment: Never try to override the `value` attribute in HtmlHelpers. Set the value of `userName` to its default value in the controller method before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: I would do so if worked with EditorFor, but it's just an Editor. It's not connected to my model, it's just additional field to get data from.

Comment: It makes no difference if you use `Editor()` or `EditorFor()`. Just give `userName` as value in the GET method. If its not a model property then you doing it wrong, but you can always use `ViewBag.userName="defaultValue";`

Comment: Man, you are awesome :) Works great! Can you, please, post an answer so it can be set as a correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not attempt to override the `value` attribute in the HtmlHelpers. Instead set the default value in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

You have indicated `userName` is not a property of your model (in which case you should be using a view model), but you can use

```
ViewBag.userName = "yourDefaultValue";
```